# using spherical coordinates in opengl

Tags: c++11, math, opengl, spherical-coordinate

I am trying to plot points around a center point using spherical coordinates. I know this is by far not the most efficient way to plot a sphere in OpenGL but i want to do it as an excersive to understand spherical coordinates better.

I want to step through each point by a certain angle so for this i have  a nested for loop itterating through theta 0 - 360 and phi 0-360 and i am attempting to get the Cartesian coordinates of each of these steps and display it as a single point.

so far i have this:

```
float r = 1.0;
for( float theta = 0.0; theta < 360.0; theta += 10.0){
    for(float phi = 0.0; phi < 360.0; phi += 10.0){

        float x = r * sin(theta) * cos(phi);
        float y = r * sin(theta) * sin(phi);
        float z = r * cos(theta);
    }
}
```

i store these points a display them. the display function works fine as i have used it to display other point structure before but for some reason i can't get this to work.

I have also tried converting the angles from degrees to radians:

```
float rTheta = theta * M_PI * 180.0;
float rPhi = phi * M_PI * 18.0;
```

as `sin()` and `cos()` both use radians but it yields the same results.

Am i doing something wrong and badly misunderstanding something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the conversion from degrees to radians of angle `x`, the correct formula is `x * M_PI / 180.`.

Comment: thank you this was causing a lot of issues. i have also realised i was not seeing the actual output due to my own stupidity as well as this -__-